# What to do when someone with more reputation trying to mislead my question into an opinion based question?

Tags: discussion

I have asked this question: [Is there any way to check for badblocks that use uncompressible data and also also can do multiple pass?](https://superuser.com/questions/1606689/is-there-any-way-to-check-for-badblocks-that-use-uncompressible-data-and-also-al)

Apparently I expect an answer to come up with a good way to test badblocks. But a user @dirkt is trying to mislead my question by posting **his opinion**. There is has no source code to support **his opinion** so I have to argue. He is saying *modern* disks does not need to check for badblocks, but at least what to do for *non-modern* disks? Anyway I just want methods to test badblocks not want to debate on opinions. But it appears this user has more reputation and the question get flagged as opinion-based and closed.

So what to do with someone with more reputation trying to mislead my question into an opinion based question? It appears he abused his reputation to express his opinions not really want to provide methods to solve questions.

Comment: If the user *answered*, then it's highly unlikely that said user voted to close the question. And their answer sounds authoritative enough that I don't really think it alone suggests to people the question is opinion based. So, I'd be wary of accusing the user for somehow causing the close votes.

Comment: @VLAZ I have searched a lot on the topic and the linked urls are provided, I see no evidence to make that answer *authoritative*. At least how about *non-modern* disks? Are we only meant to throw away *non-modern* disks? I just want methods on checking badblocks on them, why it's opinion based?

Comment: I meant "authoritative tone". As in, something the user was sure of, not just guessing at. At any rate, I really don't see a basis for the accusation here. You're free to think the user is wrong. I'm not an expert, so I can't really say. However, what I *can* say is that the situation you describe "User misleads others into voting for opinion based" is not what I see in that question. There is one answer, which might or might not be wrong, but I don't see how it changes the attitude to the question.

Comment: @Nublia Any question needs to be limited in scope - if you're not interested in modern devices, you may be better served on our Retrocomputing site, which focuses on older devices. I think it's fair for people on SU to assume that you're interested in currently-produced devices unless you explicitly state that you are interested in old devices but if the answer for the two groups of devices would be significantly different, then it's likely better served as two separate questions.

Comment: @Catija What is the real difference between *modern* and *non-modern*. How can you define modern or not for others? I'm sure drives  produced **this year** have bad blocks! I have tested a USB drive a few months ago and it did have bad blocks (**this is real**)!! So I really want a method to test badblocks for HDDs/SSDs/USB drives in general.

Comment: If you want to know why your question was closed, you'll find the answer in the banner. It seems you believe that the user who posted the answer also voted to close the question. Does it say so on the banner? I lack the necessary rep to see who closed your question. It might have been voted to close by a mod or by five users.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - The user who answered did not vote to close.

Comment: Nublia, three things: This site is the incorrect site to ask "What to do ..." **unless** you want to know *in general* and don't want to protest that your question should be reopened, you need to ask on https://meta.superuser.com/ to get it reopened (**after** you review and possibly edit to ensure that any potential for there to be any opinion based portion has been addressed). You can also do a tag search on that site (and others) to look for an answer:   https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bad-blocks+ssd

Comment: It's, well, decades since bad blocks were handled outside of the drive controller.  They are just  not an issue unless you manufacture drives.  I would be surprised if such data was even exposed over the regular interface and driver soft/firmware.

Comment: @Rob Thanks following your suggestion, it's editted and asked here https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14332/can-i-get-this-question-question-reopened. The workflow obviously has problems it's wasting a lot of time on reopening than get the real questions solved. Can they highlight the portion to be opinion based like git or wikipedia? Can it give a button to reopen the questions after address the portion?

Comment: @MartinJames So what to do with drives do expose badblocks? I have used tens of USB drives and I do have USB drives produced this year exposed a lot of badblocks to me. It is an issue. If I just use it without test, it will cause data loss. How can we know if it's good or not without checking for badblocks?

Answer (score 5):

The two things are unrelated.

It's a *perfectly* reasonable answer, though a source or two would be *educational* - and modern is pretty much any drive you'd have gotten in over a decade. The answer was posted in good faith, and it seems unfair to blame it for the closure.

I suspect that having a good answer would discourage closure, not encourage it.

Comment: You must be wrong. I have got USB drives produced **this year** not over a decade ago. It has badblock!.

Comment: @Nublia please focus on what you asked here. We are on Meta Stack Exchange and here to discuss the issue you have with your question, *not* to offer answers or information on the original question. The clarification on "modern" is relevant it seemed you weren't sure. This isn't the place to really explain technical details about hardware, especially, since we're not expected to be experts and further it's irrelevant to the actual issue you have with the closure.

Comment: I believe voted to close the question due to how broad it was, due to how close votes are done, the close reason with the most votes are displayed. That question should be improved before it’s reopened.

Comment: @Ramhound It has been imporved, it's more specific addressing on two issues. The workflow obviously has problems. It's should have a feature to highlight the portion they think are opinion based or too broad to let me address on.

Comment: @Nublia - It wasn’t improved enough to justify using one of my limited valuable reopen vote for the day.

Comment: I mentioned that fact to point out the question could still be improved.  Some of those improvements have been raised.  I don’t see any clarification provided by the comments I have read to this question.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - It's the past decade, for another 27 days at least, then it will be the previous decade.  *I am trying to be funny.*