# Can we have a feature to highlight opinion based/too broad parts of a question, and add a button to reopen after address the parts?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

One of my questions was closed as opinion-based: [Is there any way to check for badblocks that address the two issues?](https://superuser.com/questions/1606689/is-there-any-way-to-check-for-badblocks-that-address-the-two-issues) - I'm really confused why it's opinion based.

Then a user [mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357393/what-to-do-when-someone-with-more-reputation-trying-to-mislead-my-question-into) that it wasn't necessarily closed as opinion-based:

> I believe voted to close the question due to how broad it was, due to how close votes are done, the close reason with the most votes are displayed.

So the workflow obviously has problems. It's wasting a lot of time on reopening rather than getting the real questions answered. I simply don't know the real reason why my question got closed. Can we have a feature to highlight the portion of the question that is opinion based? Can we also have a highlight feature for overly broad parts of a question? Can we have a button to reopen the questions after addressing these portions?

Comment: We don't need more bells and whistles so we can cater more questions. In the end you still need 3 reviewers that are sane enough to click re-open. If they don't then the question needs work, not the curation process. Did you consider re-trying that question (in its latest revision) on the Unix & Linux site? If you check their help center you can judge if it might fly there.

Comment: Actually, I’ve always liked the idea of highlighting specific parts of a question for close-voting, e.g. _Paragraph 1 is duplicate of question X, paragraph 2 is duplicate of question Y, paragraphs 3 through 4 are opinion based_, etc.

Comment: I'm sure that some curators would be happy to provide extended info.  The only issue I can see is how you are going to pay them?

Comment: @MartinJames They are paid by the **real solutions of problems** which including my contribution. In this case, I have searched a lot of site by asking the question on badblocks this is my contribution, if someone comes up good methods to check for badblocks everyone will be happy, curators are paid by a solution of saving their data.

Comment: @rene How to re-try the question on the Unix & Linux site? Do I just open another question on that site or is there a way move and reopen it?

Comment: First read thier [on-topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and other relevant guidance, search for your problem there in case it is already answered and/or has similar questions. Include what you searched for and (not) found in your question. Then you delete on super user, copy the question markdown and create a new post on U&L. Make sure to customize it. For example: include which  linux distro you use, if you tried other distros, which filesystem (if that matters).

Comment: Your question still needs work before I can justify using one of my limited daily reopen votes.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I don't have that backstory. I still think guiding future visitors and this OP to the help center of other SE sites and advice on doing research before posting is sane. I believe the communities on SE are stronger and better equipped to deal quickly with posts that don't fit. We don't have to win this OP over. The next visitor reading all this will better understand what we expect on an SE site.

Answer (score 12):

There's two factors at play here.

1. You were the victim of a split close vote.  Because all sites have an odd number of votes needed to close a question, the reason with the most close votes is displayed.  In this case it was "too broad".
2. There's no way to highlight exactly what is too broad if the entire question is considered to be too broad.  You would have better luck taking it to that site's Meta and asking what needs to be fixed, with an eye towards being humble and trying to improve the services.